# Solve a numeric equation

Tags: matlab, math, equation, equation-solving

I would like to solve the following equation in MATLAB:

> L=(9.81.*P.^2)./(2.*pi).*tanh(2.*pi.*(d./L))

The `P` and `d` are predefined vectors. `L` is the variable to be solved to.

I try to solve this problem with:

```
%First guess
L0 = 1.56 * P;
fsolve( @(L)  L - (9.81.*P.^2)./(2.*pi).*tanh(2.*pi.*(d./L), L0 )
```

The upper code doesn't work.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Does it yield incorrect results, does it run ito errors?

Comment: gives an error input need two arguments

Comment: Can you add some small example `P` and `d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your unbalanced statement - you are missing a `)`.
Try this:

```
L0 = 1.56 * P;
your_function = @(L)  L - (9.81.*P.^2)./(2.*pi).*tanh(2.*pi.*(d./L))
fsolve(your_function, L0)
```